# Cant access to phpmyadmin using XAMPP

Tags: url, xampp, joomla

I was working on a website in my localhost with XAMPP, everything worked fine til:

I changed the URL re-writing in the global settings of Joomla (to remove index.php from the url.)  then i was able to work usually on the site, but the links on the menu broke and then i got an error page.

Then my Windows updated to the last version, and now i cant even login to the admin area or even go to phpmyadmin.

So im not sure what really happened.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Apache and PHP are running.

Probably XAMPP isn't running at the moment if you can't get to Joomla or PHPMyAdmin.

If it is running, it's likely either that you need to update XAMPP to match your Windows update, or you need to reconfigure it.